# How to display social site links in websphere poertal V7 site page

Tags: lotus, websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm

I need to display Social site links for Facebook (Like) , Tweet , and YouTube.
How to display these links in a portlet content.

Thanks in Advance ,
Pranav

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you to get started:

- [Integrating Facebook pages with business portals](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Demo_Integrating_Facebook_pages_with_business_portals)
- [Creating and Using a Rendering Plugin to Embed a Video from YouTube](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_and_Using_a_Rendering_Plugin_to_Embed_Video)